# Convert Image to Byte[]

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have an image that sits inside some folder in my MVC3 application. In my controller, how do I convert that image into a Byte array.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes("foo.png");
```

and because that's inside a controller you probably want to calculate the path relative to the root:

```
string imageFile = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), "foo.png");
byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(imageFile);
```